# Tampermonkey, Chrome, how to change html entities back to symbols?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tampermonkey

There's a webpage that messes up html code by embedding it within another html code and when I try to replace the entities with their symbol equivalents, it just removes everything.

Here's the code I tried:

```
var marks = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
      for(var i = 0, l = marks.length; i < l; i++)
      {
         var mark = marks[i];
         mark.innerHTML = mark.innerHTML.replace('&lt;', '<');
         mark.innerHTML = mark.innerHTML.replace('&gt;', '>');
         mark.innerHTML = mark.innerHTML.replace('&amp;', '&');
      }
```

but here's what it does: https://jsfiddle.net/rkb89odm/2/

Comment: Can you tell if the problem lies in the replace call, or when you assign to innerHTML?

Comment: When I try to replace it with other text, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're only replacing the first occurrence, not all occurrences.

```
> '&lt;html&gt;&lt;body&gt;'.replace('&lt;', '<')
< "<html&gt;&lt;body&gt;"
> '&lt;html&gt;&lt;body&gt;'.replace(/&lt;/g, '<')
< "<html&gt;<body&gt;"
> '&lt;html&gt;&lt;body&gt;'.replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>');
< "<html><body>"
```

See [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Second, I would avoid round-tripping partially valid markup through the browser, as it might not be the same when it comes back to you. Run all the replacements before putting it back in innerHTML.

```
let s = mark.innerHTML;
s = s.replace(/&lt;/g, '<')
s = s.replace(/&gt;/g, '>');
mark.innerHTML = s;
```

Comment: It worked for the most part, but after loading non-breaking spaces and + signs appear as &nbsp; and &#43; and I can't replace them the same way.

Comment: Nevermind, had to replace the & sign separately, thank you for helping.